# How to exclude slow loading pages from Google analytics average site speed

Tags: performance, google-analytics

I am administering a large website that I would like to ascertain what the average site speed time is.  I'm aware that there are a couple of pages that have really slow load times but would like to exclude these just to see if they are skewing the data significantly.  Does anyone one know how to do this in Google analytics at all?

thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot prevent the load times from being collected (that's part of the GA pageview call), but you can exclude URLs from the report either with the ad hoc filter above the data tables (click on "advanced" to see the exclude option) or by building a segment ("where page does not match regex <url-pattern>). However that's a reporting question and might not be strictly on-topic.

Comment: That is great.  Thanks so much for your help.